# How to format datetime in Edit view & details view in Sugarcrm?

Tags: datetime, sugarcrm

How to format datetime in Edit view & detail view in Sugarcrm?
I want to standardize the datetime format in one or more modules.

[image]

I tried some changes in customCode, but not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Which field are you trying to reformat? If it's "Date Escalated" then that does not look like a "datetime" field.

Comment: Ya, Date Escalated is a datetime field, just the time is not inserted, the actual value is : 2016-01-12 00:00:00.

Comment: Have you tried reformatting the value by utilizing preDisplay() or display() in view.edit.php and view.detail.php?

Comment: Yes, it will work. But I wish to change it under meta file(detailviewdefs.php):

'customCode' => '{$fields.date_entered.value}',

Possible to format the date at here?

Comment: if u want to standardized check the date settings in admin page, before rendering the date from the database it will be formatted into a format set in the admin page